# Will multiple category descriptions effect my search engine optimization?

Tags: posts, custom-field, search, seo

I plan to use the category descriptions as outputted content into my posts for site user searches within my site, but I want to know when I make the site live to search engines will that presence of multiple category descriptions (duplicates) effect my seo in a negative way, i.e. getting blacklisted.

So I will used the category description value in a custom field of a post, so that users can search the custom field of a post and get results of any posts with that category description.

I would just use the search everything plugin, but unfortunately it doesn't work together with the existing search fields of my particular theme. My theme's advanced search allows multiple fields searches at the same time, which I need for dual search criteria.

This goes back to reason why Im outputting the category description into a custom field of my post. I need to include all post meta content to be searchable, but because my theme is limited in that area I have to use an altenative solution, by directly inputted the value into the post to that it can be searched through a custom field.

Will this negatively effect my search engine rankings? If there any tips or advice on other solutions for what Im trying to achieve please let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get blacklisted. Small descriptive duplicate content on the same url tends to be a non-factor since it is very common, duplicate content over multiple urls, different parent urls, or large amounts of it can often become diluted, thus the use of canonical urls.

ps. This question has nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Wyck! It's good to know that the work that I put in so far wasn't for nothing. This question does have *something* to do with wordpress. Because Im not sure how the wordpress platform is treated by search engines, it's important for me to know if duplicate content as I explained, would negatively effect my site. With other types of websites (non-blog), duplicate content can hurt hurt seo, so this was very helpful. I appreciate your help, thanks.